# What should be used instead of deprecated RotaryEncoder.getScaledScrollFactor() method?

Tags: wear-os

Method `getScaledScrollFactor` in the `android.support.wearable.input.RotaryEncoder` class is now deprecated, but there is no explanation of what should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/input/RotaryEncoder):

> getScaledScrollFactor(Context context) This method is deprecated. use
> either getScaledVerticalScrollFactor(ViewConfiguration, Context) or
> getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor(ViewConfiguration, Context) instead

Answer (score 1):

Now that `RotaryEncoder` is completely deprecated, its methods should be replaced with methods from `com.google.android.wearable.input.RotaryEncoderHelper`.

Comment: When I use Ctrl+B in Android Studio to look at the decompiled class RotaryEncoderHelper, its static methods all just throw RuntimeException("Stub!") when called. So the code will compile, but it will not work.

Comment: @HendrikFrans It will work. This happens because the implementation is provided by Android and is available at runtime but not at compile time. You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70512534/5821000 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39913711/5821000

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you. I always download the sources for the SDK, so I am not used to seeing such stubs. The lack of implementation code for RotaryEncoderHelper presumably has to do with Wear OS / wearable code not all being open source like that of its Android basis.