# AnimatorSet class return RuntimeException("Stub!")

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button

I tried to made a android FAB animation toolbar. I was using this example https://github.com/vpaliyX/FAB-Toolbar-Example to check how it works, but I notice a strange thing. The AnimatorSet class in cloned example looks fine but when I try to open it in my project Ive got this. It is the implementation or import issue ?

```
package android.animation;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public final class AnimatorSet extends Animator {
    public AnimatorSet() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void playTogether(Animator... items) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void playTogether(Collection<Animator> items) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void playSequentially(Animator... items) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void playSequentially(List<Animator> items) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public ArrayList<Animator> getChildAnimations() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setTarget(Object target) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setInterpolator(TimeInterpolator interpolator) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public TimeInterpolator getInterpolator() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public AnimatorSet.Builder play(Animator anim) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void end() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public long getStartDelay() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setStartDelay(long startDelay) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public AnimatorSet setDuration(long duration) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setupStartValues() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setupEndValues() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void pause() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void resume() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void start() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public AnimatorSet clone() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String toString() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public long getTotalDuration() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public class Builder {
        Builder() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public AnimatorSet.Builder with(Animator anim) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public AnimatorSet.Builder before(Animator anim) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public AnimatorSet.Builder after(Animator anim) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

        public AnimatorSet.Builder after(long delay) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IDE is decompiling a framework class (`android.animation.AnimatorSet`). The real implementation is linked in at runtime (e.g., [7.1.1's version](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-7.1.1_r22/core/java/android/animation/AnimatorSet.java)).

Comment: So its correct in this case? What its odd, that in one project it decompiling class but in the other not.

Comment: "What its odd, that in one project it decompiling class but in the other not" -- you may not have downloaded the source code for all Android versions from your SDK Manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651148/sqlitedatabase-getwritabledatabase-throw-new-runtimeexceptionstub)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see the sources of android framework classes then you need to download them from the SDK manager.
Open the SDK manager, look for "sources for Android **x**" where **x** is android version you're developing for and download it.